He doesn’t go fishing with friends(,) as he once promised [ [not] to]
I am trying to translate a sentence.
Which is the correct interpretation?

He doesn’t go fishing with friends(,) as he once promised. = He doesn’t go fishing with friends, as he once promised to.
He doesn’t go fishing with friends(,) as he once promised. = He doesn’t go fishing with friends, as he once promised not to.

Does the meaning depend entirely on the context, as in these?

John can't keep his word. He doesn’t go fishing with friends(,) as he once promised.
John keeps his word. He doesn’t go fishing with friends(,) as he once promised.


It's ambiguous. Without any context, I think most would assume interpretation 1.

"doesn't go" is also a strange tense in this sentence. It would be more idiomatic to say "didn't go" or "isn't going".

@Barmar Thanks! I guess that "Nowadays he doesn’t go..." and "He still doesn't go..." might change the idiomaticity, might it not?

Yes. "doesn't go" describes a habitual (non-)activity, so putting it in a time frame like that os common.
